# European put option- Delta Hedge

Tags: finance, mathematical-modeling

I am studying for the first time European Put Option and Delta Hedge that is related to Black Scholes.

I would like to know how can I solve this problem:

A trader wants to sell 10 Put Options at 300$. How would you Delta Hedge your exposure on this contract and how would the hedge be managed over 6 months until the exercise date?

I have the following information:

Risk-free interest rate: 3%;

Strike price: 1900$

Stock price: 1790$

Annual volatility: 0.222

I am trying to find online examples but until now I could not find anything, also, I am not sure if this is related to the topic "Delta hedging of a stock position using options".

Can anyone give any tip in how to start?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough information. What is the stock trading at now? Does it pay dividends?  What is the riskless rate?  What diffusion process ought we to assume?  If, say, you want Black-Scholes then what volatility ought we to assume?

Comment: More to the point, this is not a good forum for question of this sort.  you might do better at https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am sorry, I edited my question with all the information I have. Thanks

Comment: Once again, you fail to specify which diffusion model you have in mind.  That's what makes this a non-math problem, the choice of model.  Presumably you just mean Black Scholes but who knows?  If so, there are plenty of Black-Scholes calculators online, or you can just write your own.

Comment: More broadly:  Black Scholes option pricing is a very well documented topic.  Under a fairly standard (and not-surprising) set of assumptions, this model provides a way to dynamically hedge in the value of the option.  You can easily find texts/websites which go over this. [Hull and White's book](https://www.amazon.com/Options-Futures-Other-Derivatives-9th/dp/0133456315) used to be the standard reference but perhaps it has been superseded.

Comment: Yes, it is related to Black Scholes

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.